# How to give users a choice of which button they want to load up

Tags: python, tkinter

First of all I'm a beginner so sorry if I format my question a bit noob-like. 
I'm making a countdown application for League of Legends which will allow you to track enemy cooldowns, I made a simple interface with tkinter which allows you to press a button which starts a cooldown and displays a message when it comes to 0.

My problem is that I can only make one set of preset buttons, but I want to let the user choose which spells he wants to track for each player, and I don't know how to achieve that.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

#This is just a countdown code for each summoner (I've got 9 of those but there's no need to paste them all)
def Flash():
    def work():
        sec = 5
        timeLoop=True
        while timeLoop:
            sec -=1
            time.sleep(1)
            if sec == 0:
                print ("Flash off cd", end = " ")
                break
    import _thread
    _thread.start_new_thread(work, ())

def Ignite():
    def work():
        sec = 5
        timeLoop=True
        while timeLoop:
            sec -=1
            print(str(sec), end=" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            if sec == 0:
                print ("Ignite off cd", end = " ")
                break
    import _thread
    _thread.start_new_thread(work, ())

p1= Label(root, text="Player1")
p2= Label(root, text="Player2")

p1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
p2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

button1 = Button(root, text="Flash",bg="orange", fg="white", command=Flash)
button2 = Button(root, text="Ignite", bg="red", fg="white", command=Ignite)

button1.grid(column=0, row=1)
button2.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Since I'm a beginner I don't even know how to google what I want correctly and hours of research just amounted to a lot of dead ends.

It counts down just like I want.
But I want to be able to switch summoners inbetween players through the actual pop up window (like with some sort of a menu)

Comment: First of all, welcome on stackoverflow. Then, could you please provide us a scheme, picture or precise description of the result you expect ? Because you explain us briefly what you try to do, but we need something more explicit. Also remember that we're not here to give you code but to give you hints. Here's a link that could interest you : [The Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering that fast, I've looked up the menu widget, but since it uses the "command" command it will just run the part of the code (for lets say Flash) and it will start counting down immeadiately. I want the menu to just let me choose which buttons do I want to load for each player (not execute them right away)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the purpose of the `Menu` . You'd have to put in there some tools to add/edit/remove your buttons. And then, each button should run a command when clicked which create and edit its own label. 
For now you're sticked with 2 labels and 2 buttons, try to make it more dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction I'll try tinkering with it a bit cheers :)